# Android Homescreen-Widget OnClick in PendingIntent is loosing Extras

Tags: android, listview, android-widget

My App has a widget. After my last Update (with AppCompat-Update to 24.2.0), my widget does not work any more. It is a Widget with a ListView, which should open a DetailView Activity when the user clicks on a widget item.

```
private RemoteViews createRemoteView(Context context, int appWidgetId, int minWidth) {
    // Set up the intent that starts the StackViewService, which will
    // provide the views for this collection.
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, FavlistWidgetService.class);

    // Add the app widget ID to the intent extras.
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    intent.putExtra(Const.extras.WIDGET_WIDTH, minWidth);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

    // Instantiate the RemoteViews object for the app widget layout.
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_favlist);

    // Set up the RemoteViews object to use a RemoteViews adapter.
    // This adapter connects to a RemoteViewsService  through the specified intent.
    // This is how you populate the data.
    rv.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.favlist_widget_list, intent);

    // The empty view is displayed when the collection has no items.
    // It should be in the same layout used to instantiate the RemoteViews
    // object above.
    rv.setEmptyView(R.id.favlist_widget_list, R.id.favlist_widget_empty_view);

    // This section makes it possible for items to have individualized behavior.
    // It does this by setting up a pending intent template. Individuals items of a collection
    // cannot set up their own pending intents. Instead, the collection as a whole sets
    // up a pending intent template, and the individual items set a fillInIntent
    // to create unique behavior on an item-by-item basis.
    Intent showResultIntent = new Intent(context, this.getClass());

    // Set the action for the intent.
    // When the user touches a particular view, it will have the effect of
    // broadcasting TOAST_ACTION.
    showResultIntent.setAction(Const.intents.WIDGET_SHOW_RESULT);
    PendingIntent showResultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, showResultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    rv.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.favlist_widget_list, showResultPendingIntent);

    Intent showAppIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
    PendingIntent showAppPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, showAppIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.favlist_widget_empty_view, showAppPendingIntent);

    return rv;
}
```

The WidgetService creates the RemoteViews Object, all Extras are added with a fillInIntent:

```
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    Listable item = list.get(position);

    String secondDisplayName = ListableUtil.getSecondDisplayName(item);
    int layout = StringUtils.isEmpty(secondDisplayName) ? R.layout.widget_favlist_item_oneline : R.layout.widget_favlist_item_big;
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), layout);
    rv.setTextViewText(R.id.favlist_widget_item_first, ListableUtil.getDisplayName(item));

    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(secondDisplayName)) {
        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.favlist_widget_item_second, secondDisplayName);
        rv.setImageViewResource(R.id.favlist_widget_item_icon, ListableUtil.getWidgetListIcon(item));
    } else {
        rv.setTextViewCompoundDrawablesRelative(R.id.favlist_widget_item_first, ListableUtil.getWidgetListIcon(item), 0, 0, 0);
    }

    // Next, set a fill-intent, which will be used to fill in the pending intent template
    // that is set on the collection view in StackWidgetProvider.
    Intent fillInIntent = new Intent(context, ResultActivity.class);
    fillInIntent.putExtra(Const.extras.LISTABLE_ID, item.getIdentifier());
    fillInIntent.putExtra(Const.extras.LISTABLE_TYPE, item.getClass().getName());
    fillInIntent.putExtra(Const.extras.LISTABLE, item);

    // Make it possible to distinguish the individual on-click action of a given item
    rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.favlist_widget_item, fillInIntent);
    // Return the remote views object.
    return rv;
}
```

My BroadcastReciever recieves the Intent after the user selects one entry. But the given Intent is missing the `LISTABLE` Extras.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Const.intents.WIDGET_SHOW_RESULT)) {
        LoggerFactory.get().d(StringUtils.intentToString(intent));
        GoogleAnalyticsHelper analyticsHelper = GoogleAnalyticsHelper.getInstance(context);
        analyticsHelper.trackWidgetCall();

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(Const.intents.SHOW_RESULT);

        String type = intent.getStringExtra(Const.extras.LISTABLE_TYPE);
        resultIntent.putExtra(Const.extras.LISTABLE_TYPE, type);

        long id = intent.getLongExtra(Const.extras.LISTABLE_ID, -1);
        resultIntent.putExtra(Const.extras.LISTABLE_ID, id);

        Serializable item = intent.getSerializableExtra(Const.extras.LISTABLE);
        resultIntent.putExtra(Const.extras.LISTABLE, item);

        resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(resultIntent);
    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

Does anyone has an idea, where my extras are gone? This code was working before I did the Update to the new appCompat and build tools and so on. :(

**Update:**
It looks like, that the `rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.favlist_widget_empty_view, showAppPendingIntent);` is the problem. If I remove this, everything works fine. So I cannot use an OnClick-Event on my empty-view. Any Ideas?